# VBA Excel Formula, error 1004

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm trying to input a formula in a cell after inserting a row. And VBA does not want that and returns an error.

I first copied the formula from the excel sheet, (with ";" as delimitors), and as I have seen on other threads, I replace those with ",".

I don't understand why I get the error.

```
Sub Borderx()
Dim nboc As Integer
Dim ipaste As Integer


nboc = Worksheets("BDD").Range("IQ2").Value


For ipaste = 1 To nboc - 1
    Worksheets("Bordereaux").Range("B14").EntireRow.Insert
    Worksheets("Bordereaux").Range("T14").Formula = "=IF(AND(J14="",E14=""),SUM(F14*F14*H14)/1000,IF(O14="",SUM((H14*F14*G14)+(M14*K14*L14))/1000,SUM((H14*F14*G14)+(M14*K14*L14)+(R14*P14*Q14))/1000))"

    Next ipaste          
End Sub
```

In this case, nboc = 2, and this is supposed to insert one row.
Before I added the "if" statement, it worked fine when it was just sum()

Comment: in your formula, everytime you use `""` you need to use double quotes, so use `""""` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it like this:

```
Worksheets("Bordereaux").Range("T14").Formula = " =IF(AND(J14="""",E14=""""),SUM(F14*F14*H14)/1000,IF(O14="""",SUM((H14*F14*G14)+(M14*K14*L14))/1000,SUM((H14*F14*G14)+(M14*K14*L14)+(R14*P14*Q14))/1000))"
```